# Rotate Image on hover fails

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, hover

I have the working example for rotating an image on hover [here](https://codepen.io/krakruhahah/pen/zYWzpOW)

It uses scale(), rotate() and transition properties when hovering over the parent element to animate the image.
And overflow: hidden on the parent element to hide the excess from the image transformation.

When I try to replicate the same effect on React I see the image but the image does not rotate when i hover. But its all the same? What am I missing here?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import Image from 'mui-image';

const styles = {
    hoverRotate: {
        overflow: 'hidden',
        margin: '8px',
        minWidth: '240px',
        maxWidth: '320px',
        width: '100%',
    },

    'hoverRotate img': {
        transition: 'all 0.3s',
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
        maxWidth: '100%',
    },

    'hoverRotate:hover img': {
        transform: 'scale(1.3) rotate(5deg)',
    },
};

function Rotate() {
    return (
        <Box style={styles.hoverRotate}>
            <Image src="https://picsum.photos/id/669/600/800.jpg" />
        </Box>
    );
}

export { Rotate };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way of styling doesn't detect hovers, hence use `useState` to set the hover state of the image (import it using `import { useState } from "react";`)

```js
const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);
```

Now, check if the `Box` is hovered or not, if hovered, set `isHover` to `true`, if not hovered, set it to `false`.

```js
<Box
  style={styles.hoverRotate}
  onMouseEnter={() => setIsHover(true)}
  onMouseLeave={() => setIsHover(false)}
>               
  {/* code */}
</Box>
```

Move your `styles` into the `Rotate` function. You are not assigning the key `"hoverRotate img"` to any of the styles hence it doesn't get applied. So change its name to something like `image` and add the hover code conditionally to it as shown below. The reason for moving `styles` into the `Rotate` function so that `isHover` stays in scope to get it's value.

```js
const styles = {
  hoverRotate: {
    overflow: "hidden",
    margin: "8px",
    minWidth: "240px",
    maxWidth: "320px",
    width: "100%"
  },

  image: {
    transition: "all 0.3s",
    boxSizing: "border-box",
    maxWidth: "100%",
    transform: isHover && "scale(1.3) rotate(5deg)"
  }
};
```

Finally, set the `image` style to `Image`

```js
<Image
  src="https://picsum.photos/id/669/600/800.jpg"
  style={styles.image}
/>
```

---

Checkout this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-matan-c43ufb?file=/src/App.js:829-928

Comment: Great thanks! I tried the sandbox and to use it in my code but the style={styles.image} throws this error now: 

(property) MuiImageProps.style?: React.CSSProperties | undefined
Type '{ transition: string; maxWidth: string; transform: string | false; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
  Types of property 'transform' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | false' is not assignable to type 'Transform | undefined'.
      Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'Transform | undefined'.ts(2322)

Comment: index.d.ts(28, 5): The expected type comes from property 'style' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MuiImageProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'

No idea why the styles are throwing errors as they have not before

Comment: Ok, so implementing it in your project causes errors, does the output in the sandbox works fine @AnTony?

Comment: Yes the sandbox works perfect and I just created a fresh React Typescript template and copy pasted the sandbox to try it.

Comment: @AnTony, try `const styles = { ... } as const`. I am not sure if it works or not, but my answer doesn't apply to typescript as it was not tagged to the question but react was tagged. Anyway, I will try to figure out a solution for this

Comment: Did and got a similar error: 

`Type '{ readonly transition: "all 0.3s"; readonly boxSizing: "border-box"; readonly maxWidth: "100%"; readonly transform: false | "scale(1.3) rotate(5deg)"; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
  Types of property 'transform' are incompatible.
    Type 'false | "scale(1.3) rotate(5deg)"' is not assignable to type 'Transform | undefined'.
      Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'Transform | undefined'`

I also tried to do as React.CSSProperties

Comment: @AnTony, try `const styles: CSS.Properties = { ... }` and before that, import `import CSS from 'csstype';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246694/discussion-between-geeky-quentin-and-an-tony).

Answer (score 0):

With the new [`@mui/system` styling solution](https://mui.com/system/basics/) (`sx` prop), you just need to pass the styles object to the `sx` prop:

```
import React from "react";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";

const boxSx = {
  overflow: "hidden",
  margin: "8px",
  minWidth: "240px",
  maxWidth: "320px",
  width: "100%",

  "& > img": {
    transition: "all 0.3s",
    boxSizing: "border-box",
    maxWidth: "100%"
  },

  "&:hover > img": {
    transform: "scale(1.3) rotate(5deg)"
  }
};

function Rotate() {
  return (
    <Box sx={ boxSx }>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/669/600/800.jpg" />
    </Box>
  );
}

export { Rotate };
```

If you are missing the old [`@mui/styles` (now deprecated) styling solution](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/), you are missing `makeStlyes`, and then passing the resulting styles to the `className` prop:

```
import React from "react";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import makeStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  hoverRotate: {
    overflow: "hidden",
    margin: "8px",
    minWidth: "240px",
    maxWidth: "320px",
    width: "100%",

    "& > img": {
      transition: "all 0.3s",
      boxSizing: "border-box",
      maxWidth: "100%"
    },

    "&:hover > img": {
      transform: "scale(1.3) rotate(5deg)"
    }
  }
});

function Rotate() {
  const styles = useStyles();

  return (
    <Box className={ styles.hoverRotate }>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/669/600/800.jpg" />
    </Box>
  );
}

export { Rotate };
```

Comment: Thanks but when I try to apply your solution I see the image but it does not rotate at all. I tried the sx approach as the second one is deprecated by mui

Comment: @AnTony My bad, in the `sx` version there should not be a `hoverRotate` prop inside the object. I've updated the first example, it should work now.